# HTTP header 400 bad request response

Tags: http

I'm trying to test writing correct HTTP headers to understand
the syntax. Here I'm trying to PUT some text into httpbin.org/put and I expect the response body content to be the same.

```
PUT /HTTP/1.1
Host: httpbin.org
Accept-Language: en-us
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-type: text/plain
Content-Length: 12 

Hello jerome
```

However I'm getting the following bad request 400 response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2016 12:34:02 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 166
Connection: close
Response:

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

What syntactical errors have I done?
NOTE: newlines are \r\n not \n in the request.

Comment: how are you making the request/

Comment: I'm using sockets in c. I want to break the abstraction most languages provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the correct syntax goes like this for PUT:

```
   PUT /put HTTP/1.1\r\n
   Content-Length: 11\r\n
   Content-Type: text/plain\r\n
   Host: httpbin.org\r\n\r\n
   hello lala\n
```

I believe I didn't say much on how I connected to httpbin.org; it was via sockets in C. So the connection was already established before sending the header + message.

Comment: I got the same thing too when trying to simulate your output in Node.js

Answer (score 0):

You miss the destination url following the PUT verb, the first line must be:

```
PUT http://httpbin.org/ HTTP/1.1
```

This will probably also fail, you need one of their handler urls so they know what to reply with:

```
PUT http://httpbin.org/put HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: Should I leave all other fields intact (ie host)

Answer (score 0):

The general form of the first line, or Request Line, in an HTTP request is as follows:

```
<method> <path component of URL, or absolute URL> HTTP/<Version>\r\n
```

Where for your example, the method is PUT. Including an absolute URL (so, starting with `http://` or `https://` is only necessary when connecting to a proxy, because the proxy will then attempt to retrieve that URL, rather than attempt to serve a local resource (as found by the path component).

As presented, the only change you should have needed to make was ensuring there was a space between the `/` and `HTTP/1.1`. Otherwise, the path would be "/HTTP/1.1"... which would be a 404, if it weren't already a badly formed request. `/HTTP/1.1` being interpreted as a path means the HTTP server that's parsing your request line doesn't find the protocol specifier (the `HTTP/1.1` bit) before the terminating `\r\n`... and that's one example of how 400 response codes are born.

Hope that helped. Consult [the HTTP 1.1 RFC (2616)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.html#section-5.1), section 5.1 for more information and the official definitions.